# offset().top doesnt count the height of chrome extention toolbar

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, iframe, toolbar, offset

I am trying to get the offset to top of an element, but it appears that if there is a some kind of Gooogle Chrome extention toolbar - it loads after the page is loaded in an iframe and its height is not counted in the offset().top.

I am running my jQuery function on (window).load(), maybe this is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good that you noticed that was happening. It might be best practice to make calculations in the window's onResize event:

```
$(window).load(function() { $(window).trigger('resize'); });

$(window).resize(function() {
  // get offset().top; calculation here, when window loads and each time window is resized.
});
```

Also, you could post a full example of your code (css, html, js) in a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I have a hunch that .position() would work better than .offset(), possibly with some minor css/html tweaks but, we can't tell without seeing your code.